# PHP associative array equivalent in Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby

How would one write the following array in Ruby?

```
 $itemsarray = array();

 $itemsarray["items"]['0']['product_id'] = 1;
 $itemsarray["items"]['0']['brand_id'] = 1;
 $itemsarray["items"]['0']['color_id'] = 1;

 $itemsarray["items"]['1']['product_id'] = 2;
 $itemsarray["items"]['1']['brand_id'] = 3;
 $itemsarray["items"]['1']['color_id'] = 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy. Here is what you will need:

```
itemsarray = { 'items' => [ { 'product_id' => 1, 'brand_id' => 1, 'color_id' => 1 } ] }
```

Now a little bit of explanation...

In Ruby to represent an associative array we use *Hashes*. Ex.: `{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }` == `array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2)`.

So at the top level you have a hash containing the key `items` and it's value is an array of all the items. The first item is a hash again, having the product options as keys with their corresponding values.

What is a bit better way to write this is to use symbols instead of strings for the keys, as this will introduce a slight memory optimisation. Here is an example:

```
itemsarray = { :items => [ { :product_id => 1, :brand_id => 1, :color_id => 1 } ] }
```

There is also a shorthand syntax where `:abc => 1` is equivalent to: `abc: 1`, so the above line would look like:

```
itemsarray = { items: [ { product_id: 1, brand_id: 1, color_id: 1 } ] }
```

**UPDATE**

With multiple items, here is how it would look like:

```
itemsarray = { items: [
                          { product_id: 1, brand_id: 1, color_id: 1 },
                          { product_id: 2, brand_id: 3, color_id: 5 }
                      ]}
```

Or a dynamic approach:

```
itemsarray[:items].push( { product_id: 2, brand_id: 3, color_id: 5 } )
```

Comment: Great explanation, I knew this, however, I wanted to be able to add multiple 'items'. I changed the question a bit to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, the issue was syntactic. I was using the closing array bracket incorrectly. It's late here. ;)

Comment: @Jason Updated answer to reflect changes in the question

Comment: @Jason did you get this to work? looks like printaura api, i'm battling it over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453190/api-post-with-array-using-http-gem-or-restclient if you think you could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
itemsarray={ items:[{product_id:1, brand_id:1, color_id:1} ]}
```