# API POST with array using HTTP gem (or RestClient)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest-client, http.rb

I'm having trouble with this api and can't seem to get over the hump.  Using the [HTTP gem](https://github.com/httprb/http) (though I'm flexible and can use [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) if that gets me an answer quicker!).  Anyway, I'm having trouble posting an array.  everything else is good, I just can't figure out this "itemsarray" in the printaura api found here in the addorder method: [PrintAura API](https://printaura.com/api/)

I'm running this:

```
def self.submitorder   
  req = HTTP.post("https://api.printaura.com/api.php", :json => { 
        :key => APIKEY, 
        :hash => APIHASH, 
        :method => "addorder",
        :businessname => "this is a secret too",
        :businesscontact => "thats a secret",
        :email => "my@email.com",
        :your_order_id => "1",
        :returnlabel => "FakeAddress",
        :clientname => "ShippingName",
        :address1 => "ShippingAddressLine1",
        :address2 => "ShippingAddressLine2",
        :city => "ShippingCity",
        :state => "ShippingState",
        :zip => "ShippingZip",
        :country => "US",
        :customerphone => "dontcallme",
        :shipping_id => "1",
        :itemsarray => {:item => [ 
            :product_id => 423,
            :brand_id => 33,
            :color_id => 498,
            :size_id => 4,
            :front_print => 1389517,
            :front_mockup => 1390615,
            :quantity => 1
          ]}

    })

  puts JSON.parse(req)




end
```

And my output is this:

```
{"status"=>false, "error_code"=>19, "result"=>19, "message"=>"You cannot place an order without items, Please fill the items array with all the required information. Full API documentation can be found at https:/www.printaura.com/api/"}
```

Gosh, if someone could look at that and help me out I would forever appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def self.submitorder 
  itemsarray = { :items => [ { :product_id => 423, :brand_id => 33, :color_id => 498, :size_id => 4, :quantity => 1, :front_print => 1389517,
        :front_mockup => 1390617 } ] }
  req = HTTP.post("https://api.printaura.com/api.php", :json => { 
    :key => APIKEY, 
    :hash => APIHASH, 
    :method => "addorder",
    :businessname => "this is a secret too",
    :businesscontact => "thats a secret",
    :email => "my@email.com",
    :your_order_id => "1",
    :returnlabel => "FakeAddress",
    :clientname => "ShippingName",
    :address1 => "ShippingAddressLine1",
    :address2 => "ShippingAddressLine2",
    :city => "ShippingCity",
    :state => "ShippingState",
    :zip => "ShippingZip",
    :country => "US",
    :customerphone => "dontcallme",
    :shipping_id => "1",
    :items =>  Base64.encode64(itemsarray.to_json)}
)

  puts JSON.parse(req)
```

I really hopes this helps somebody some years from now haha

Answer (score 1):

To create a array in JSON you use an array in Ruby. Its that easy.

```
require 'json'

def self.submitorder   
  req = HTTP.post("https://api.printaura.com/api.php", :json => { 
        :key => APIKEY, 
        :hash => APIHASH, 
        :method => "addorder",
        :businessname => "this is a secret too",
        :businesscontact => "thats a secret",
        :email => "my@email.com",
        :your_order_id => "1",
        :returnlabel => "FakeAddress",
        :clientname => "ShippingName",
        :address1 => "ShippingAddressLine1",
        :address2 => "ShippingAddressLine2",
        :city => "ShippingCity",
        :state => "ShippingState",
        :zip => "ShippingZip",
        :country => "US",
        :customerphone => "dontcallme",
        :shipping_id => "1",
        :items => [ 
           {
             :product_id => 423,
             :brand_id => 33,
             :color_id => 498,
             :size_id => 4,
             :front_print => 1389517,
             :front_mockup => 1390615,
             :quantity => 1
           }
        ]
    })

  puts JSON.parse(req)
```

The API lists a `items` parameter which should contain an array of objects. It says nothing about `itemsarray`.

Comment: That didn't work, same message.  I'm so puzzled.  I had tried that earlier, too.  I just thought since it changed from $postfield to $itemsarray in the php example on their documentation I needed to make an 'itemsarray'