# Substitute to an escaped shell string?

Tags: ruby, bash

I want to substitute ruby variable to an escaped shell string.

This is what I start with, and it works:

```
<<~`SHELL`
  curl -s "#{CANVAS_URI}/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions" \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{ "question": { "question_type": "multiple_choice_question", "question_text": "<p>Is everything clear?</p>", "points_possible": 1, "answers": [ { "text": "I read and understood", "html": "", "weight": 100 }, { "text": "I have questions", "comments_html": "<p>Please post your questions to a discussion (in course navigation).</p>", "weight": 0 } ] } }' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer #{CANVAS_TOKEN}"
SHELL
```

However I want `discussion` (in a `-d JSON`) to be a link. And can't get it to work:

```
myJson = %Q|{ "question": { "question_type": "multiple_choice_question", "question_text": "<p>Is everything clear?</p>", "points_possible": 1, "answers": [ { "text": "I read and understood", "html": "", "weight": 100 }, { "text": "I have questions", "comments_html": "<p>Please post your questions to a <a href="#{CANVAS_URI}/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/discussion_topics">discussion</a>.</p>", "weight": 0 } ] } }|

<<~`SHELL`
  curl -s "#{CANVAS_URI}/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions" \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '#{myJson}' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer #{CANVAS_TOKEN}"
SHELL

<<~`SHELL`
  curl -s "#{CANVAS_URI}/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions" \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "#{myJson}" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer #{CANVAS_TOKEN}"
SHELL
```

I got trapped between escaping of the two langs.

The whole thing is a workaround of posting nested json in ruby. Flat jsons works in most of the http gems, but getting nested json is a rare need, and I'm afraid most gems did not test against it (I remember trying http.rb to do this, but even json array are [non trivial there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475686/788700).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem, you'd have to be careful to escape everything with `Shellwords.escape` and then not quote them.

```
<<~`SHELL`
  curl -s "#{CANVAS_URI}/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions" \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d #{Shellwords.escape(myJson)} \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer #{CANVAS_TOKEN}"
SHELL
```

But this is tedious and error prone and not really your problem.

> *The whole thing is a workaround of posting nested json in ruby. Flat jsons works in most of the http gems, but getting nested json is a rare need, and I'm afraid most gems did not test against it...*

Nested JSON is not rare, and there should be no reason an http client cares about the contents of your JSON anyway. It's just transmitting a string.

Your JSON is malformed. Specifically here:

```
"comments_html": "<p>Please post your questions to a <a href="#{CANVAS_URI}/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/discussion_topics">discussion</a>.</p>"
```

You have an unescaped quote. This is probably because you're putting your nested JSON together by hand. Like shelling out to curl, this is error prone.

---

Instead, create a Ruby hash and convert that to JSON. Then you get all the benefit of Ruby's syntax checking.

```
payload = {
  question: {
    question_type: "multiple_choice_question",
    question_text: "<p>Is everything clear?</p>",
    points_possible: 1,
    answers: [
      {
        text: "I read and understood", 
        html: "", 
        weight: 100
      }, {
        text: "I have questions",
        comments_html: %Q[<p>Please post your questions to a <a href="#{CANVAS_URI}/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/discussion_topics">discussion</a>.</p>],
        weight: 0
      }
    ]
  }
}

require "json"
json_payload = JSON.generate(payload)
```

And instead of calling `curl`, use an http library. Since you're calling a REST API, you can use [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).

```
require "rest-client"
response = RestClient.post(
  "#{CANVAS_URI}/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions",
  json_payload,
  { content_type: :json, authorization: "Bearer #{CANVAS_TOKEN}" }
)
```

Or, even better, use the [canvas-api gem](https://github.com/whitmer/canvas-api) which takes care of the JSON conversion and can take advantage of API features like pagination.

```
canvas = Canvas::API.new(:host => CANVAS_URI, :token => CANVAS_TOKEN)
response = canvas.post(
    "/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions",
    payload
)
```

Comment: I like the RestClient and Canvas approaches, backticks (and `system(command_string)`) rank up there with "useless use of cat" (except the cat is also angry and wielding razors).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're taking the wrong approach. Mixing string interpolation with backticks or the single argument version of `Kernel#system` is messy and dangerous. You're better off bypassing the shell and its quoting issues entirely and using the multi-argument form of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

```
system(
  'curl',
  '-s', "#{CANVAS_URI}/api/v1/courses/#{COURSE_ID}/quizzes/#{quiz_id}/questions",
  '-X', 'POST',
  '-H', "Content-Type: application/json",
  '-d', myJson,
  '-H', "Authorization: Bearer #{CANVAS_TOKEN}"
)
```

That will directly execute `curl` with the supplied arguments without involving a shell at all. If you need to save `curl`'s response, use [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) from the standard library and again avoid the shell and its quoting problems.